# What is the difference between "a lot of friends" and "lots of friends"?

Tags: phrases, collocations, countable-nouns

I am wondering whether there are differences in meanings between following two expressions.

> I used to have a lot of friends 5 years ago.
>
> I used to have lots of friends 5 years ago.

As a non-native English speaker, I cannot find any difference between these two.
Please enlighten me if there are differences in nuances.

Comment: The difference is at least one lot. But we don't know the size of the lot(s). So we cannot conclude anything about the number of friends, other than that the speaker believes them to have been "many". One lot = 5/8 of an oodle.

Answer (score 2):

Both the phrases "a lot of" and "lots of" are used in infornal styles to refer to a large number or amount of things or people. These phrases are interchangeable.  However, the latter is more informal.

So both the sentences presented by the OP have the same meaning.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.
I assume I should not use either of them under formal circumstances...

Comment: @Kyozy You are correct.  A more formal wording is, "I had many friends 5 years ago".

Answer (score 0):

To a native English (British) speaker I think they have somewhat different implications for the number of friends you have now. So I would use them thus:

> "I used to have a lot of friends 5 years ago, now I only have a few."

or

> "I used to have lots of friends 5 years ago, now I don't have any."

As a further point, one usually avoids "I used to have ... 5 years ago", instead saying "I had ...", since "5 years ago" implies that whatever you are talking about is no longer the case, making "used to" unnecessary. Therefore

> "I had a lot of friends 5 years ago, now I only have a few."

or

> "I had lots of friends 5 years ago, now I don't have any."

I should say I don't think these are strict interpretations and could probably be used either way if wanted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!
I understood as "a lot of" > " lots of".
Now I got the clue to use them under best fit situation!
Thank you!

Comment: @Kyozy, in AmE, "a lot of" > ""lots of" would be a bad assumption.  The phrases are ambiguous as to how many people they refer to, or which is greater.  It might be driven by context, and I would guess an even split as far as which phrase people tend to associate with the greater number.  Also, the usage examples in the answer must be a BrE thing; there's no similar implication in AmE.  But interesting answer.

Comment: Yes @fixer1234 I should be clear "a lot of" and "lots of" are indistinguishable in terms of size.  Also my answer is definitely my own feeling about it - not advice/a rule that I have ever seen written down!